# GLSL3 Tangent space coordinates and normal mapping

Tags: glsl, shader, texture-mapping, light, bump-mapping

First of all, I must apologize for posting yet another question on this subject (there are a lot already!). I did search for other related questions and answers, but unfortunately none of them showed me the solution. Now I'm desperate! :D

It is worth mentioning that the code posted below gives a satisfying 'bumpy' effect. It is the scene enlightenment that seems to be wrong.

**The scene:** is dead simple! A cube in the center, a light source rotating around it (parallel to the ground) and above.

My approach is to start from my basic light shader, which gives me adequate outputs (or so I think!). The first step is to modify it to do the calculations in tangent space, then use the normal extracted from a texture.

I tried to comment the code nicely, but in short **I have two questions**:

1) Doing only basic lighting (no normal mapping), I expect the scene to look exactly the same, with or without transforming my vectors into tangent space with the TBN matrix. Am I wrong?

2) Why do I get incorrect enlightenment?

A couple of screenshots to give you an idea (EDITED) - following LJ's comment, I am no longer summing normals and tangent per vertex/face. Interestingly, it highlights the issue (see on the capture, I have marked how the light moves).

> Basically it is as if the cube was rotated 90 degrees to the left, or, as if the light was turing vertically instead of horizontally

Result with normal mapping:

[image: Result with normal mapping]

Version with simple light:

[image: Version with simple light]

**Vertex shader:**

```
// Information about the light. 
// Here we care essentially about light.Position, which
// is set to be something like vec3(cos(x)*9, 5, sin(x)*9)
uniform Light_t Light;

uniform mat4 W; // The model transformation matrix
uniform mat4 V; // The camera transformation matrix
uniform mat4 P; // The projection matrix

in vec3 VS_Position; 
in vec4 VS_Color;
in vec2 VS_TexCoord;
in vec3 VS_Normal;
in vec3 VS_Tangent;

out vec3 FS_Vertex;
out vec4 FS_Color;
out vec2 FS_TexCoord;
out vec3 FS_LightPos;
out vec3 FS_ViewPos;
out vec3 FS_Normal;

// This method calculates the TBN matrix:
// I'm sure it is not optimized vertex shader code,
// to have this seperate method, but nevermind for now :)
mat3 getTangentMatrix()
{
    // Note: here I must say am a bit confused, do I need to transform
    // with 'normalMatrix'? In practice, it seems to make no difference...
    mat3 normalMatrix = transpose(inverse(mat3(W)));
    vec3 norm = normalize(normalMatrix * VS_Normal);
    vec3 tang = normalize(normalMatrix * VS_Tangent);
    vec3 btan = normalize(normalMatrix * cross(VS_Normal, VS_Tangent));
    tang = normalize(tang - dot(tang, norm) * norm);
    return transpose(mat3(tang, btan, norm));
}

void main()
{
    // Set the gl_Position and pass color + texcoords to the fragment shader
    gl_Position = (P * V * W) * vec4(VS_Position, 1.0); 
    FS_Color = VS_Color;
    FS_TexCoord = VS_TexCoord;

    // Now here we start:
    // This is where supposedly, multiplying with the TBN should not
    // change anything to the output, as long as I apply the transformation
    // to all of them, or none.
    // Typically, removing the 'TBN *' everywhere (and not using the normal 
    // texture later in the fragment shader) is exactly the code I use for 
    // my basic light shader.
    mat3 TBN = getTangentMatrix();
    FS_Vertex = TBN * (W * vec4(VS_Position, 1)).xyz;
    FS_LightPos = TBN * Light.Position;
    FS_ViewPos = TBN * inverse(V)[3].xyz;

    // This line is actually not needed when using the normal map: 
    // I keep the FS_Normal variable for comparison purposes, 
    // when I want to switch to my basic light shader effect.
    // (see later in fragment shader)
    FS_Normal = TBN * normalize(transpose(inverse(mat3(W))) * VS_Normal);
}
```

**And the fragment shader:**

```
struct Textures_t 
{
    int SamplersCount;
    sampler2D Samplers[4];
};

struct Light_t 
{
    int   Active;
    float Ambient;
    float Power;
    vec3  Position;
    vec4  Color;
};

uniform mat4 W;
uniform mat4 V;
uniform Textures_t Textures;
uniform Light_t    Light;

in vec3 FS_Vertex; 
in vec4 FS_Color;
in vec2 FS_TexCoord;
in vec3 FS_LightPos;
in vec3 FS_ViewPos; 
in vec3 FS_Normal;

out vec4 frag_Output;

vec4 getPixelColor()
{
    return Textures.SamplersCount >= 1 
        ? texture2D(Textures.Samplers[0], FS_TexCoord)
        : FS_Color;
}

vec3 getTextureNormal()
{
    // FYI: the normal texture is always at index 1
    vec3 bump = texture(Textures.Samplers[1], FS_TexCoord).xyz;
    bump = 2.0 * bump - vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    return normalize(bump);
}

vec4 getLightColor()
{
    // This is the one line that changes between my basic light shader
    // and the normal mapping one:
    // - If I don't do 'TBN *' earlier and use FS_Normal here, 
    // the enlightenment seems fine (see second screenshot)
    // - If I do multiply by TBN (including on FS_Normal), I would expect
    // the same result as without multiplying ==> not the case: it looks
    // very similar to the result with normal mapping 
    // (just has no bumpy effect of course)
    // - If I use the normal texture (along with TBN of course), then I get
    // the result you see in the first screenshot.
    vec3 N = getTextureNormal(); // Instead of 'normalize(FS_Normal);'

    // Everything from here on is the same as my basic light shader
    vec3 L = normalize(FS_LightPos - FS_Vertex);
    vec3 E = normalize(FS_ViewPos  - FS_Vertex);
    vec3 R = normalize(reflect(-L, N)); 

    // Ambient color: light color times ambient factor
    vec4 ambient = Light.Color * Light.Ambient;

    // Diffuse factor: product of Normal to Light vectors
    // Diffuse color: light color times the diffuse factor
    float dfactor = max(dot(N, L), 0);
    vec4  diffuse = clamp(Light.Color * dfactor, 0, 1);

    // Specular factor: product of reflected to camera vectors
    // Note: applies only if the diffuse factor is greater than zero
    float sfactor = 0.0;
    if(dfactor > 0)
    {
        sfactor = pow(max(dot(R, E), 0.0), 8.0);
    }

    // Specular color: light color times specular factor
    vec4 specular = clamp(Light.Color * sfactor, 0, 1);

    // Light attenuation: square of the distance moderated by light's power factor
    float atten = 1 + pow(length(FS_LightPos - FS_Vertex), 2) / Light.Power;

    // The fragment color is a factor of the pixel and light colors:
    // Note: attenuation only applies to diffuse and specular components
    return getPixelColor() * (ambient + (diffuse + specular) / atten);
}

void main()
{
    frag_Output = Light.Active == 1 
        ? getLightColor() 
        : getPixelColor();
}
```

That's it! I hope you have enough information and of course, your help will be greatly appreciated! :) Take care.

Comment: Without looking at your code, from the images it looks like your cube consists of 8 shared vertices with gouraud normals?! So your normals aswell as your tangents are wrong, gauraud shading is used to approximate smooth surfaces, a cube is certainly not a smooth surface. Before you do anything else fix your surface normals(hint they should be perpendicular to the surfaces, extra hint: yes that means no shared vertices).

Comment: Many thanks LJ - gouraud normals were not the root of the problem, but your remark made the problem more obvious I find: now the face on the left is always in the light, as if it was on top - and the one the right (not visible on the screenshot) is always in the dark!

Answer (score 0):

I am experiancing a very similar problem, and i can not explain *why* the lighting doesn't work right, but i can answer your first question and at the very least explain *how* i somehow got lighting working acceptably (though your problem may not necesarrily be the same is mine).

Firstly in theory *if you tangents and bitangents are calculated correctly*, then you should get exactly the same lighting result when doing the calculation in tangentspace with a tangentspace normal [0,0,1].

Secondly while it is common knowledge that you should transform your normals from model to cameraspace by multiplying by inverse transpose model-view matrix [as explained by this tutorial](http://web.archive.org/web/20120228095346/http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Illumination/Tut09%20Normal%20Transformation.html), i found that the problem with the lighting being transformed wrong can be solved if you transform the normal tangent by the model-view matrix rather than the inverse transpose model-view. Ie use `normalMatrix = mat3(W);` instead of `normalMatrix = transpose(inverse(mat3(W)));`.

In my case this did »fix« the problems with the light, **but i don't know why this fixed it, but i make no guarantee that it does not (in fact i assume that it does) introduce other problems with the shading**